# startingOffset and endingOffset in pyspark structured-streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using pyspark 2.4.5 to consume message from Kafka. For batch query, there are 2 options `startingOffset` and `endingOffset` can be used to read specific message on Kafka.
I'm quite confused with the example in Spark document:

[image: document of integration guide between pyspark and kafka]

I don't understand the example for configuration with JSON format:

```py
""" {"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}} """
```

My questions are:

- what does the configuration `"0": 23` mean?
- This configuration is used for consuming multiple topics, if I read only 1 topic A then what does the configuration look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A kafka topic consists of multiple partitions where each partition would have its own offset. So a starting offset of `{"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1},"topicB":{"0":-2}}` would mean:

| Topic | Partition | Offset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| topic1 | 0 | 23 |
| topic1 | 1 | -1 |
| topic2 | 1 | -2 |

Meaning for -1 and -2 are already specified in the doc. In case you are not familiar with kafka partitions, there are many good explanations out there like [this](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/apache-kafka/partitions/).

For single topic, it would be simply: `{"topicA":{"0":23,"1":-1}}`